# How to close connection after Multipart Upload completes in VertX

Tags: java, kotlin, upload, vert.x

I'm building a streaming upload in VertX so that I can stream an upload directly to a Google Cloud / AWS S3 bucket, but the upload never seems to end when looking at the network tab in the browser.

This is the test upload form I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" value="blah">
    <input multiple type="file">
</form>
<div>

</div>
<script>
    let input = document.querySelector("input[type='file']")
    let div = document.querySelector("div")
    input.addEventListener("change", event => {
        let files = event.target.files
        console.log(files)
        const formData = new FormData()
        for (let file of files) {
            formData.append(file.name, file)
            formData.append("blah", "blah")
        }
        window.fetch("http://localhost:11111/le-upload-test?testing=true", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData
        }).then(response => {
            div.innerHTML = ""
            div.append(`${response.statusText} - ${response.status}`)
            console.log(response)
        })
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the backend,

```
class MyServer(
    val port: Int,
) : CoroutineVerticle() {

    val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.javaClass)

    init {
        Vertx.vertx()?.deployVerticle(this) 
            ?: throw Exception("Failed to start VertX")
    }

    override suspend fun start() {
        vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler { req ->
            println(req.path())
        
            if (req.path() == "/le-upload-test") {
                req.isExpectMultipart = true
                req.uploadHandler { upload ->
                    println("==================")
                    println(req.params())
                    println(upload.filename())
                    println("==================")
                    upload.handler { chunk ->
                        println("chunk.length=${chunk.length()}")
                        println("total.read=${req.bytesRead()}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }.listen(port)
    }
}

fun main() {
    MyServer(
        port = 11111,
    )
}
```

When uploading multiple files, this correctly outputs:

```
/le-upload-test
==================
testing=true

Screenshot_20201026_211340.png
==================
chunk.length=239
total.read=422
chunk.length=8192
total.read=8614
chunk.length=8192
...
==================
testing=true

Screenshot_20201026_181456.png
==================
chunk.length=192
total.read=74150
chunk.length=7770
total.read=81920
...
```

At what point should I be calling `req.response.end("...")`?

Unless I restart the server, the browser just hangs there indefinitely?

[image]

I've tried doing:

```
req.uploadHandler { upload ->
    val contentLength = req.getHeader("Content-Length")
    upload.handler { chunk ->
        if (req.bytesRead().toString() == contentLength) {
            println("DONE!!")
            req.response().setStatusCode(200).end("DONE")
        }
    }
}
```

This correctly prints DONE when all the bytes are processed, but the browser then shows failed, `EMPTY RESPONSE`.

Adding an `upload.endHandler` after `upload.handler`

```
    upload.endHandler {  end ->
        println("DONE!!!")
        req.response().setStatusCode(200).end("TEST")
    }
```

does print the `DONE!!!` part correctly when all the bytes are processed, but also never closes the upload connection with a status 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working, seems all it was missing was  a CORS header

```
    override suspend fun start() {
        vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler { req ->

            println(req.path())
            try {
                if (req.path() == "/le-upload-test") {

                    req.response().putHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

                    req.isExpectMultipart = true
                    req.uploadHandler { upload ->
```

```
                    req.endHandler {                        
                        req.response().end("BLAH!!")
                        println("DONE")
                    }
```

[image]